# How to replace UTF-8 codes in a PHP string with real characters?

Tags: php, character-encoding, utf

I execute openssl shell command from PHP and get the following string as an output string segment from that: `'Divisi\xC3\xB3n TeleComunicaciones'`. There are Spanish characters substituted by their literal UTF-8 codes, as far as I understand.
I need to replace the codes with their Spanish character equivalents. The resulting string must look like the following: 'División TeleComunicaciones'?

I tried many PHP string conversion functions, but none succeeded.
I also noticed one thing. When I define a variable as

`$var = "Divisi\xC3\xB3n TeleComunicaciones"` it is echo-ed correctly ('División TeleComunicaciones')

But if I take the value from the openssl shell command output it always is printed as `'Divisi\xC3\xB3n TeleComunicaciones'`.

Can anybody advice, please, does PHP have any built-in means for this purpose?

Comment: Well sir, mind me asking if you've taken a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ?

Comment: I've updated the question definition. That is my 1st question here. Please be tolerant, and help me to align it with the stackoverflow practices. I have lack of experience with that

Comment: Do `openssl -utf8 ...`.

Comment: Unfortunately "openssl req -in csr.txt -noout -subject -utf8" returns the same output with eascape codes

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a single byte-escaping string, you can convert them by using a regular expression:

```
echo preg_replace("#(\\\x[0-9A-F]{2})#e", "chr(hexdec('\\1'))", $var);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does work for this case and majority of others including even Chinese character!
But doesn't work for a Cyrillic string: "\x04\x12\x04>\x047\x04=\x045\x04A\x045\x04=\x04A\x04:". This must be "Вознесенск", but I get: ">7=5A5=A:". Doyou have any idea why Cyrillic is an exception here?

Comment: Could you tell me what the charset is from the outputted data?

Comment: Actually the value is stored in a field of a CSR file I decode with openssl. When I feed the same file to comodo online decoder it recognizes value "Вознесенск" correctly in that field, but openssl outputs me "\x04\x12\x04>\x047\x04=\x045\x04A\x045\x04=\x04A\x04:".